# How do I create a field output URL?

Tags: views, 8

For the multilingual Drupal 8 based website I have created a view with a list of nodes. On the top of the page I have implemented a custom block with a autocomplete textfield, the textfield returns a JSON response with all available languages. After selecting the language, I want to update the fields (titles), so that they are displayed in the language, selected by the user.

The approach I am thinking about is after submitting the textfield, update the fields output. But for this I would need to create some URL for the fields output. How can I create a URL for the fields section with Drupal tools? Is it possible to distinguish the areas on the view? Please, help.

Comment: Why not just use the Exposed Language filter instead of a custom Block?

Comment: Exposed language filter triggers the interface language. But in my case I just need to translate the titles inside of one view

Answer (score 1):

You can not update the output of some part of views from custom block without actually rendering the views again.
You have to reload the views using ajax request/ simple http request (as you prefer) with the langcode in views argument.

What you can do is add a global contextual filter in the view, Use that contextual filter's value in [template_preprocess_views_*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/8.5.x) listed here, If contextual value is not empty.